# angular 2 date is not rendered with pipe date

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 beta 12.

When I do:

```
  <div *ngFor="#s of items">
        <div style="font-weight:bold;">
            <p>{{ s.startDate }}</p>
            <p>{{ s.endDate | date }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The startDate is displayed.

The endDate using the date pipe does not display the date!

How must the datetime string 'endDate' look like that it is a 'valid' date string for the date pipe?

Comment: are `endDate` and `startDate` in correct format?

Comment: The format for startDate which is displayed fine is: '2014-09-10T00:00:00' the endDate has the same format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format seems to be invalid. You should see some error messages on your console.

Try to wrap your date into a JS Date Object with `endDate = new Date(endDate);`

Comment: You are right I see now a error message in the console output.